# I need help about this old code ereg_replace

Tags: php, mysql, eregi

Good morning from Italy and sorry for my bad English :)

In to an old web application i need to make some change but i receive this `warning` :

`ereg_replace` is `deprecated` etc etc

I try to change :

```
eregi_replace("([0-9]*)(\/)([0-9]*)(\/)([0-9]*)","\\5-\\3-\\1",GetSQLValueString($_POST['dataordine'], "date")),
```

with :

```
preg_replace("([0-9]*)(\/)([0-9]*)(\/)([0-9]*)","\\5-\\3-\\1",GetSQLValueString($_POST['dataordine'], "date")),
```

but dont work ->

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '(' in \www\testate_ins.php on line 23
```

What can i do ?

Thank you vary much for the help.

Bye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put '/' on the begining and the end of pattern like this

```
"/([0-9]*)(\/)([0-9]*)(\/)([0-9]*)/"
```

and it should work.

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier ')' in \www\testate_ins.php on line 23

Comment: preg_replace("/([0-9])(/)([0-9])(/)([0-9]*)/","\5-\3-\1",GetSQLValueString($_POST['dataordine'], "date")),

Comment: Ok, this one from your last comment is not the same as the one above. For the last one you can use bounding character '|' instead of '/'. So it would be
"|([0-9])(/)([0-9])(/)([0-9]*)|"

Comment: No Warning but insert in to DB value 0000-00-00

Comment: Sorry I didn't see replace string. Use this $5-$3-$1 instead of \5-\3\1 :)

Comment: now work fine. tnx very much